# Wrong result of select into

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I would like to check some values in `BEFORE TRIGGER` but values are different from what I can see in database.

This is my trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TAH_BEFORE
BEFORE INSERT ON TAH
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_HRA_ID number := -1;
  V_OBLAST_ID number := -1;
  V_RESULT number := -1;
BEGIN

  V_RESULT := -1;
  begin
    select H.ID, H.OBLAST_ID into V_HRA_ID, V_OBLAST_ID from HRA H where H.STAV_ID  = 0;
    exception
      when no_data_found
      then raise_application_error(-20001, 'No game in playing state.', TRUE);
  end;

  begin
    select P.SHOWN into V_RESULT from POLE P where P.OBLAST_ID = V_OBLAST_ID and P.ROW_ID = :new.ROW_ID and P.COL_ID = :new.COL_ID;
    if V_RESULT > 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Already shown.' || V_RESULT || ' ' || V_OBLAST_ID || ' ' || :new.ROW_ID || ' ' || :new.COL_ID, TRUE);
    end if;
  end;

  begin
    select count(M.ID) into V_RESULT from MINA M
    join HRA H on H.OBLAST_ID = M.OBLAST_ID
    where H.id = V_HRA_ID;
    if V_RESULT > 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20003, 'This field is marked as mine.', TRUE);
    end if;
  end;

  :new.TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  :new.HRA_ID := V_HRA_ID;
END;
```

If I run

```
Insert into TAH(ROW_ID, COL_ID) VALUES(5,5);
```

I get error message

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
insert into TAH (ROW_ID, COL_ID) VALUES (5, 5)
Error report -
ORA-20002: Already shown.1 143 5 5
ORA-06512: na "SK1X1.TAH_BEFORE", line 29
ORA-04088: chyba během provádění triggeru 'SK1X1.TAH_BEFORE'
```

But if I check database with select (or I check table data in GUI of oracle sqldeveloper) ALL of rows in `POLE` table have `SHOWN = 0`.
First `insert into` with `VALUES(4,4)` went fine without error. But since than, every next one (with different values) give me this error. Did I wrote something wrong in trigger?

**edit**
DDL of tables `POLE` and `HRA`

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table POLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "ROW_ID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "COL_ID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "OBLAST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VALUE" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "SHOWN" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table HRA
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "FIRST_MOVE" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT '01-01-17', 
    "LAST_MOVE" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT '01-01-17', 
    "TAGGED_MINES_COUNT" NUMBER(4,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "STAV_ID" NUMBER, 
    "OBLAST_ID" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index POLE_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SK1X1"."POLE_PK" ON "SK1X1"."POLE" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index HRA_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SK1X1"."HRA_PK" ON "SK1X1"."HRA" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger POLE_TRG
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SK1X1"."POLE_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON POLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT POLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "SK1X1"."POLE_TRG" ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger HRA_TRG
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SK1X1"."HRA_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON HRA 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT HRA_SEQ1.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "SK1X1"."HRA_TRG" ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table POLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "POLE_CHK1" CHECK (shown in ( '1', '0' )) ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "POLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("ROW_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("COL_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("OBLAST_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("VALUE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."POLE" MODIFY ("SHOWN" NOT NULL ENABLE);
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table HRA
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" ADD CONSTRAINT "HRA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "STUDENTS2014"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("TAGGED_MINES_COUNT" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("STAV_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("OBLAST_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("FIRST_MOVE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SK1X1"."HRA" MODIFY ("LAST_MOVE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Comment: `First insert into went fine without error. But since than, every next one give me this error. `  - Are you inserting the same row again n again ? Condition in second begin block is getting executed which means there already exists the data

Comment: Of course not :-) for first time I use values 4,4. But now I get error for every value I try
I will edit this in my op

Comment: Can you please post the table DDL with some sample data to simulate your error.

Comment: I posted DDL of two tables. Is this enough?

Comment: Please see the modified working code for me

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason which look to me is  when you execute the select statement of the second being block. You simple do

`select P.SHOWN into V_RESULT from...` Here not sure what datatype of the column `P.SHOWN`. Might be some implicit converstion is happening. So it's good to take `count(P.SHOWN)` into `v_rsult`.

Try this:
EDIT: - I modified the code as per the amount of information provided by you and its working fine for me. See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TAH_BEFORE
BEFORE INSERT ON TAH
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_HRA_ID number := -1;
  V_OBLAST_ID number := -1;
  V_RESULT number := -1;
BEGIN

  V_RESULT := -1;
  begin
    SELECT H.ID, H.OBLAST_ID 
    INTO V_HRA_ID, V_OBLAST_ID 
    from HRA H where H.STAV_ID  = 0;
    exception
      WHEN no_data_found
      --then raise_application_error(-20001, 'No game in playing state.', TRUE);
      then dbms_output.put_line( 'No game in playing state.');
  end;

  BEGIN
    SELECT count(P.SHOWN) 
      INTO V_RESULT 
    FROM POLE P 
    WHERE P.OBLAST_ID = V_OBLAST_ID 
    AND P.ROW_ID = :NEW.ROW_ID 
    AND P.COL_ID = :NEW.COL_ID;

    if V_RESULT > 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Already shown.' || V_RESULT || ' ' || V_OBLAST_ID || ' ' || :new.ROW_ID || ' ' || :new.COL_ID, TRUE);
    end if;
  END;
/*
  begin
    select count(M.ID) into V_RESULT from MINA M
    join HRA H on H.OBLAST_ID = M.OBLAST_ID
    where H.id = V_HRA_ID;
    if V_RESULT > 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20003, 'This field is marked as mine.', TRUE);
    end if;
  end; */

  --:NEW.TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  --:new.HRA_ID := V_HRA_ID;
END;
```

Execution:

```
Insert into TAH(ROW_ID, COL_ID) VALUES(5,5);
Insert into TAH(ROW_ID, COL_ID) VALUES(4,4);
```

Output:

```
select * from tah;

Row_id  Col_id
-----   ------
5         5
4         4
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Shown is NUMBER(1,0). I tried also rewrite into count, bud still same error

Comment: Can you please post the table DDL with some sample data to simulate your error.

Comment: Thanks again for edit. I tried, but still the same. I think that the sql server have some problem with me :-(

Comment: The question was tagged for Oracle PlSql not SQL server. Are you trying in SQL server?

Comment: Nope, its in Oracle sqldeveloper

Comment: @Sk1X1. I posted the working for you. Its working as you can see the output.